# How to Edit and delete jQuery data table each rows

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

How to edit and delete jQuery data table each rows.I am using jQuery dataTables.js Library.

Is there any function to do that..i am new for the dataTables.js

Comment: http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html

Answer (score 0):

use code like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    $('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( '../examples_support/editable_ajax.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "14px"
    } );
} );
```

reference **[editable jquery datatable](http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html)**